# Déité et divinité

Tags: vocabulaire, synonymes, religion

Y a-t-il des différences entre les mots *divinité* et *déité* ? Peut-on employer l'un à la place de l'autre indifféremment ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Y a-t-il des différences entre les mots divinité et déité ?

Peu de différence de signification, déité est souvent synonyme de divinité quand il exprime la nature divine comme quand il représente l'être divin lui-même.

> Peut-on employer l'un à la place de l'autre indifféremment ?

Ce ne serait probablement pas une bonne idée. *Déité* est très rare en littérature et ne s'emploie quasiment plus dans la langue moderne où il pourrait ne pas toujours être compris, voire être pris pour un anglicisme.

[image]

C'est d'ailleurs peut-être en partie à cause de l'influence de *deity* que son usage est en légère croissance depuis une centaine d'années, mais toujours sans commune mesure avec son pendant anglais.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Dans l'usage littéraire (*), je ne crois pas que l'on fasse vraiment de différence.

Les exégètes testamentaires mettent une différence très formelle et ce, dès le grec ancien qui distingue *θεότης* (que l'on a traduit par *déité*) et *θε**ι**ότης* (divinité).
La Septante utilise les deux termes différemment :

- θεότης (déité) : C'est Dieu absolument. (Et donc Jésus aussi par définition)
- θε**ι**ότης (divinité) : Ce sont les attributs divins.

NDaCOSwt... (pour se marrer...) les Grecs ont toujours été très forts pour faire d'énormes différences de sens avec de simples iotas qui, pour passer parfois inaperçus des copistes... autoriseront certaines *"hérésies"* à se tirer d'embarras certains... ;)

(*) Entendre celui de Hugo, Balzac, Chateaubriand... par opposition à celui des écrits testamentaires et de leurs exégètes.

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord avec la première phrase. Dans l'usage courant (au moins l'usage courant moderne), *déité* n'existe pas. C'est important à noter pour les lecteurs anglophones, parce qu'en anglais, *deity* est d'usage relativement courant.

Comment: @Gilles : Dans l'usage courant... de qui ? Bon... je veux bien comprendre ce que tu veux dire au sens ou, oui, le mot n'est effectivement pas courant. Mais... ce qui n'empêche pas pour autant son usage d'être courant... chez ceux qui... l'utilisent. Je réalise néanmoins que l'opposition d'usage, telle que présentée dans la contribution ci-contre est assez bancale. Je modifie donc.

Comment: @aCOSwt autre source : le Trésor de la langue française comptabilise parmi 416 ouvrages du XIXème siècle et 586 du XXème siècle une fréquence littéraire absolue de 53 pour "déité" contre *2033* pour "divinité". Soit un rapport de près d'un à quarante.

Comment: @aCOSwt > Le language courant, c'est le language courant. Le language courant des membres de l'académie française entre eux, ca n'est pas le language courant. Ngram et autres sont d'ailleurs là pour indiquer à quel point un mot est courant ou pas.